# Having trouble extending a Javascript function with more functions

Tags: javascript, function, overriding

I'm trying to override a Javascript function that is included in a .js file that I cannot modify(it is served from a server our applications aren't deployed on). The function contains functions and variables within it. There is one sub-function that I need to change the behavior of but it is called by another, I can't call it directly. Here it is:

Simplistic version of included file that I can't change:

```
com.company.topLevelFunc = function () {
  var a = null;
  var b = null;
  var doSomething = function() {
    a = foo;
    b = bar;
  };
  var get = function(cfg) {
    //do stuff
  };
  return {
    //other vars and functions here
    getValue : function (cfg) {
      cfg.url=a + b;
      get(cfg);
    }
  };
}();
```

The function I need to override is the get(cfg). However, I can't call it directly, I need to go through the getValue(cfg) method and preserve all the other stuff that goes on in the top level function. So I've been trying to override both as follows:

My JS that I full control over, and doesn't work, it errors on the apply saying that 'missing : after property id". Am I doing this correct, not sure how to get the apply to work correctly?

```
var topLevel = com.company.topLevelFunc;
myTopLevel = function() {
  var myGet = function(cfg) {
    //do simliar but different stuff from the original get function
  };
  return {
    topLevel.apply(this, arguments);
    getMyValue : function (cfg) {
      cfg.c= a + b +"some other string";
      //do something
      myGet(cfg);
    }
  };
}();
```

Comment: `Am I doing this correct?` Have you attempted to check your result to catch some obvious syntax errors like the extra ()  in the first example and the apply call in the second one?

Comment: I removed the () in the 1st example, it was a typo typing it into this forum, thanks. I don't get any other syntax errors, just the error "missing : after property list" on the apply call. I'm not sure why, maybe I don't understand how the apply works and am not using it correctly or in the right place. My intent was to get the original top level function into the same state as if I were calling getValue rather than getMyValue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, the get method is private. It only exists inside the body of a an anonymous function nobody has access to. Aside from some very clever hacks and unrecommended programming, there is nothing you can do to change it.

What you should do in this case is change the `getValue` property of `com.company.topLevelFunc`. The way you are attempting to do that is slightly wrong and i will explain why.

```
a = function() { // this is not a
  var c = function() { return 3; };
  return { // this object is a
    b : c;
  }
}(); // called immediately
```

In this construct, `a` is not a function. The function you see there is invoked immediately and a is assigned the return value of that invocation. In fact this is almost equivalent:

```
a = { b : function() { return 3; } };
```

Why you would use the first construct instead of the second is a question asked many times here. A short answer is that the first allows you to have private stuff that nobody else can access (like your get method).

So a is an object with a property who's value is a function that returns 3. If you want a to return 4, you need to do something like this:

```
a.b = function() { return 4; }
```

This keeps the other properties of `a` intact (if it had any) and only changes the property you are interested in.

If you want b to access some private properties defined in the anonymous function above, it simply cannot be done.